# BigQuery IS NOT NULL where condition not working

Tags: google-bigquery, nested, where-clause

I am trying to create a table in BigQuery using the following command. In my  raw dataset, the 'customDimensions' is a nested column with 2 sub-fields: value and index. In my query, I want to have a where condition to filter out record with customDimensions.value IS NOT NULL. However, in my output data, there are still records with PCF_CUST_ID is null. Why my where condition does not work?

```
create table `putput_folder.output_data` as
select visitId
      ,(select value FROM t.customDimensions where index = 4) AS PCF_CUST_ID
from `input_folder.input_data_*` as t, UNNEST(customDimensions) as customDimensions
where _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20210101' and '20210131' and customDimensions.value is not null
order by visitId;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
select
  visitId,
  cd.value as PCF_CUST_ID
from `input_folder.input_data_*` as t
left join unnest(customDimensions) cd
where _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20210101' and '20210131'
  and cd.index = 4 and cd.value is not null
order by visitId
```

Your original query was selecting every `visitId`, regardless of them having an `index=4`.

Comment: Thank you so much it works!